# Is there a way to avoid casting when dealing with Hashtables in C#?

Tags: c#, casting, hashtable, associative-array

I'm wondering is there a way to overwrite Hashtable (or Dictionary) class so it would automatically do boxing/unboxing operations on objects. In other words:

```
myHashtable["value1"] = "this_is_string";
myHashtable["value2"] = 123;

string a = myHashtable["value1"];
int b = myHashtable["value2"];
// errors as expected, since i need to cast it to specific type from object
```

And apparently C# doesn't allow overwriting **public T this[object key]** operator with different types, since I tried to do something like this:

```
public int this[object key] { get { return (base[key] as int); } set {} } // etc
public string this[object key] { get { return (base[key] as string); } set {} } // etc
// error
```

Any ideas or tips what is the simplest way (if any) to avoid casting while using associative arrays in C# (there's no need to strictly use Hashtable)? And if there's no way to do it, I would appreciate if someone more knowledgeable than me, explain why it is so and what are the fundamentals behind it.

Thank you.

**Edit:**
The reason I need it, is that I'm creating a custom Settings class. Settings might have different types of values, such as let's say "HowManyItemsToDisplay" would have some integer value, while "NameOfSomeControl" would be a string. Therefore it would be nice to avoid any casting when writing something like:

```
myControl.Text = MySettings["SomeTextValue"];
```

or

```
while (MySettings["SomeIntValue"] > 0) { .. }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a good reason for doing this you could write an extension method to give you a reasonable way simulate that:

```
myHashTable.GetAs<string>("value1");
myHashTable.GetAs<int>("value2");

public static T GetAs<T>( this Hashtable ht, object key )
{
    return (T)ht[key];
}
```

If you know the key is always a string you can make that the parameter type for the key and even use the generic dictionary or other structure with a strongly typed key.

And to be perfectly clear the casting and boxing are still there, just hidden from view.

**Additional response to edit:**

If you are able to use C# 4 I think you can pretty much get want you want syntactically with `Dictionary<object,dynamic>`.  Of course, if you are able to do that then you might just want to make the settings object dynamic and use the syntax `mySettings.Value1` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Dictionaries give you type safety, you can't just throw anything into them.  HashTables are not generic and use objects so you are forced to box / unbox.  The short answer is **no** you cannot overwrite this functionality for a HashTable.  The answer is to use generics if you can.

Unless you are targeting an older .net framework I'd say stick to the generic dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

you could dynamically cast using object.GetType()

Comment: You are still boxing / unboxing here.

Answer (score 0):

C# is strongly typed (ok, they are weakening this, but at its core...)

You usually use a Dictionary specifying the type of the Key and the Value

You want a dictionary where the value can be any type, and still retrieve the value in a type-safe manner.  To me this indicates that you are trying to program C# as if it were a weakly-typed language, using a hash instead of creating a class to store a collection of related values.

In idiomatic C#, you seldom have reason to store different value-types in the same dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you know that the Types are predefined, it is always nice to use the Generic version of a Collection like :

List instead of ArrayList, Array
Dictionary instead of HashTable  in turn KeyValuePair instead of object

Generic version of Stack & Queue etc.

It is important, even though  lots of legacy code even inside Microsoft BCL uses non-generic collections, but for new development, generics are always a preferred choice.

Even you can use [Generic Variance introduced with .NET 4.0](http://dailydotnettips.com/2011/06/29/working-with-co-variance-and-contra-variance-in-net-4-0/) if you require.